# SmartfaceEmulator [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]

Tags: android, smartface.io

I am trying to evaluate Smartface.
Using the example included I cannot use the "Device Emulator" connecting a Samsung S5 with lollipop (USB debug enabled and not signed apk allowed)

this is what it writes:

```
Checking Android SDK Configuration.
Searching for Devices...
Device found: SM-G900F
Generating Exporting Packages for Android profile:"Default"
    Pages, JavaScripts files are preparing
    Project resources are preparing
    Datasets are preparing
    Installation packages are creating
Installing Emulator...
```

After waiting several minutes it also writes:

```
Application could not install to  
 Error Message :    pkg: /sdcard/SmartfaceEmulator.apkFailure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]
 Same issue again? Please refer to Troubleshooting document!
 An error occured on launch! Please launch Smartface Emulator manually on your Android device.
```

Even trying to install the apk manually after uploading in the phone it does not work, it says App not installed.

do you have any hint? I tried to look for the problem over internet without success.
regards

Comment: Lollipop uses ART instead of Dalvik. Just based on the error message that is where I would start.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I have had a look and this might be the problem, but my understanding now is that the only one that can solve it is the "smartface" producer.

Answer (score 0):

try updating your s5, the initial version of android lollipop on it is broken (multidex lib) so samsung did fix that and made new update. i faced it too with my s5.

Answer (score 0):

Exact same issue for me on my S5 updated to the latest version of android.

The update doesn't fix it.